# How do you do forward declarations in arduino code?

Tags: macos, arduino

I am trying to compile the polargraph code for arduino that someone else wrote. As far as I know the code itself is correct and after I add in the libraries needed to run it I get this error message.

> polargraph_server_polarshield.ino:109:16: error: 'prog_uint32_t' does not name a type
>       In file included from /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/Arduino.h:28:0,
>                        from /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SPI/SPI.h:17,
>       from polargraph_server_polarshield.ino:47:
>       util.ino: In function 'long unsigned int crc_update(long unsigned int, byte)':
>       util.ino:392:31: error: 'crc_table' was not declared in this scope
>       util.ino:394:31: error: 'crc_table' was not declared in this scope
>       Error compiling.

I have heard that you need to set up a forward declaration because it uses two words in its data type and the official arduino compiler doesn't handle that well.  How do I go bout doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repo for that project has been updated since the zip bundle was made.

The line now reads:

```
const uint32_t PROGMEM crc_table[16] = {
```

(https://github.com/euphy/polargraph_server_polarshield/blob/master/polargraph_server_polarshield.ino#L108)

This change was required when Arduino IDE 1.6 came about and broke a bunch of new things!

I have since updated the code bundle to include:

- crc_table definition fix
- UTFT library update to v2.81 (for same reason - Arduino IDE 1.6 compatibility)

(https://github.com/euphy/polargraphcontroller/releases/tag/2015-07-15-21-25)

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors showing in what you provided. First, there's no declaration for **prog_uint32_t** included in the header files for some reason. So you probably need to add:

```
typedef uint32_t PROGMEM prog_uint32_t;
```

or include the right header files if anything else is missing.

You have to publish the code for the util.ino sketch to get help on the second error.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like you're coding in simple C; in that case, it's a simple C forward declaration, for example:

```
struct b;
```

Comment: @LinkReincarnate: only you can answer that, it's your forward declaration. Where you'd need it!